# Error when running unmodified archetype CXF JAX RS project

Tags: maven, tomcat, cxf, jax-rs, maven-archetype

I'm trying to run an archetype generated project :
org.apache.cxf.archetype:cxf-jaxrs-service

I used Maven to generate it and tried to run it on tomcat 7. 
I posted the code even if its not modified by me (default).

I get the same error with every URL used in the browser.
Am I missing something ?

HelloWorldIT.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.cxf.helpers.IOUtils;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.MappingJsonFactory;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HelloWorldIT {
    private static String endpointUrl;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        endpointUrl = System.getProperty("service.url");
    }

    @Test
    public void testPing() throws Exception {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(endpointUrl + "/hello/echo/SierraTangoNevada");
        Response r = client.accept("text/plain").get();
        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), r.getStatus());
        String value = IOUtils.toString((InputStream)r.getEntity());
        assertEquals("SierraTangoNevada", value);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJsonRoundtrip() throws Exception {
        List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
        providers.add(new org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider());
        JsonBean inputBean = new JsonBean();
        inputBean.setVal1("Maple");
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(endpointUrl + "/hello/jsonBean", providers);
        Response r = client.accept("application/json")
            .type("application/json")
            .post(inputBean);
        assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), r.getStatus());
        MappingJsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
        JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser((InputStream)r.getEntity());
        JsonBean output = parser.readValueAs(JsonBean.class);
        assertEquals("Maple", output.getVal2());
    }
}
```

JsonBean.java

```
public class JsonBean {
    private String val1;
    private String val2;

    public String getVal1() {
        return val1;
    }

    public void setVal1(String val1) {
        this.val1 = val1;
    }

    public String getVal2() {
        return val2;
    }

    public void setVal2(String val2) {
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Path("/echo/{input}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String ping(@PathParam("input") String input) {
        return input;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/jsonBean")
    public Response modifyJson(JsonBean input) {
        input.setVal2(input.getVal1());
        return Response.ok().entity(input).build();
    }
}
```

Error Message :

```
 javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toNotFoundException(SpecExceptions.java:89)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toNotFoundException(ExceptionUtils.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:169)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:290)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:214)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know anything about the tomcat maven plugin, but going through the configurations in the pom, it appears the port is set to `13000` and the context path to `jaxrs-service`.

Running `mvn tomcat7:run-war` from the command line, the following is successful

```
http://localhost:13000/jaxrs-service/hello/echo/Whatever
```

I believe the unit test is meant to be ran as an `intergration-test` goal. You can run

```
mvn integration-test
```

and it should start a server and you should see at the end

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I believe the above solutions starts-up an embedded container, not your actual local instance. If you launch the app from your local instance, then the url should be

```
http://localhost:8080/<name-of-war>/hello/echo/Whatever
```